# SpringSecurity: How to Continue Forwarding Request to RestController After a Successful Authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt, spring-restcontroller

I am doing a pure backend project with REST APIs (not MVC) and would like to use SpringSecurity with JWT token to project these APIs. The implementation is good and all APIs are successfully protected with the token, and I can post a JSON string with username and password to "`/login`" path to get token

My problem is:

- The SpringSecurity will return the response with token directly in `successfulAuthentication()` rather than keep forwarding to RestController (RestController's "`/login`" path gets no data)

And my question is:

- What should I do, after a successful authentication, to allow SpringSecurity can keep forwarding the request to RestController's "`/login`" path so that I can do something else on the request and the newly built token beside the security in the path?

Appreciate any helps, Thank you!

My code:

```java
@Component
public class TokenWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registry").permitAll()         // allow path /registry
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()            // allow path /login
                .antMatchers("/verify").permitAll()           // allow path /verify
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // ...
    }
}


@RestController
public class EntranceEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RestResponse<String> login(LoginMetaInfo login) {
        System.out.println(login);  // no output here when login

        // some further operations for a successful login, and return a REST response
    }
}
```

And this is what the SpringSecurity do on a successful login

```java
public class TokenLoginFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    // ...
    /**
     * on login success
     */
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException {

        // here build the token and insert into response for commitment
        // - the SpringSecurity soon returns the response directly, rather then keep forwarding to RestController
        String token = xxxx;
        response.setStatus(StatusCode.SUCCESS().getCode());
        RestResponse<String> body = RestResponse.succeeded(StatusCode.SUCCESS().withMsg(LoginResponseCode.LOGIN), token);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(MediaType.CHARSET);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), body );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should not write the value in the response. Instead you can put the value in request or session attributes and then use it in the `EntranceEndpoint`. In addition, the purpose of `successfulAuthentication` method is to set up an authenticated user in the security context - you don't need to do anything extra here.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply using HttpServletResponse's sendRedirect instead of writing to the response?

```
   @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException {

      // do what you want here

        response.sendRedirect("/login");
         // response.sendRedirect("https://yoururl");
    }
```